# How would the redux saga behave if there is multiple function call with same action in the watcher?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-saga

I am trying to call two saga function with the same Action when it is dispatched but the order of the execution of function matters.Althought i can put one of the saga inside the other to maintain the right sequence of execution.I want to know if there's a way to have two sagas run in a particular order when a single action is dispatched?

```
export default function* watcher() {
yield takeEvery(ACTIONS.INITIALIZE_PARAMS, initializeParams);
yield takeEvery(ACTIONS.INITIALIZE_PARAMS, refreshFeed);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of like asking how to manage the execution order of reducers. Each reducer manages independent parts of the state, so you can't manage it. The same thing happens with sagas that 'take' actions. If you have a direct dependency between different parts, just 'take' the action with a single saga and then handle the order the way you want.